# How to parse a csv string into a Spark dataframe using scala?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I would like to convert a `RDD` containing records of strings, like below, to a Spark dataframe.

```
"Mike,2222-003330,NY,34"
"Kate,3333-544444,LA,32"
"Abby,4444-234324,MA,56"
....
```

The schema line is not inside the same `RDD`, but in a another variable:

```
val header = "name,account,state,age"
```

So now my question is, how do I use the above two, to create a dataframe in Spark? I am using Spark version 2.2.

I did search and saw a post:
[Can I read a CSV represented as a string into Apache Spark using spark-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111918/can-i-read-a-csv-represented-as-a-string-into-apache-spark-using-spark-csv)
.
However it's not exactly what I need and I can't figure out a way to modify this piece of code to work in my case.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way would probably be to start from the CSV file and read it directly as a dataframe (by specifying the schema). You can see an example here: [Provide schema while reading csv file as a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926411/provide-schema-while-reading-csv-file-as-a-dataframe).

---

When the data already exists in an RDD you can use `toDF()` to convert to a dataframe. This function also accepts column names as input. To use this functionality, first import the spark implicits using the `SparkSession` object:

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

Since the RDD contains strings it needs to first be converted to tuples representing the columns in the dataframe. In this case, this will be a `RDD[(String, String, String, Int)]` since there are four columns (the last `age` column is changed to int to illustrate how it can be done).

Assuming the input data are in `rdd`:

```
val header = "name,account,state,age"

val df = rdd.map(row => row.split(","))
  .map{ case Array(name, account, state, age) => (name, account, state, age.toInt)}
  .toDF(header.split(","):_*)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
+----+-----------+-----+---+
|name|    account|state|age|
+----+-----------+-----+---+
|Mike|2222-003330|   NY| 34|
|Kate|3333-544444|   LA| 32|
|Abby|4444-234324|   MA| 56|
+----+-----------+-----+---+
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I need !!

Comment: Maybe this is ok when there's just a couple of lines that you can visually inspect, but generally it's not idea to parse CSV using simple split by newline and comma, because you can have those characters inside a cell value. CSV is "parsed", which is fundamentally different from simple text manipulation and even from regex pattern matching, it's preferred to use a real CSV library.